# Retirar postagens de categoria especifica wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Olá, baixei o tema dooplay e estou tentando retirar de um widget posts que sejam da categoria 764, porém não tive sucesso até agora, poderiam me ajudar nisso?

Esse é o código original da query:

```
query_posts(array(
    'post_type' => array(
        'movies',
        'tvshows'
    ) ,
    'showposts' => $num,
    'meta_key' => 'end_time',
    'meta_compare' => '>=',
    'meta_value' => time() ,
    'meta_key' => $keybox,
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'DESC'
));
```

Formas que estou tentando fazer:

```
query_posts(array(
    'post_type' => array(
        'movies',
        'tvshows'
    ),
    'category__not_in' => array(764),
    'showposts' => $num,
    'meta_key' => 'end_time',
    'meta_compare' => '>=',
    'meta_value' => time() ,
    'meta_key' => $keybox,
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'DESC'
));
```

Também utilizei

> 'cat' => '-764'

mas nenhuma dessas formas funcionou. Agradeço aos amigos que puderem me dar uma força.

Comment: Jovem esse tipo de coisa normalmente da para fazer direto pela area do administrador, nas opções do plugin etc. Vc tb pode tentar criar uma categoria nova, e mover todos os posts da 764 para essa categoria nova, depois disso despublique a 764 para ver se resolve.

Comment: Não existe essa opção, amigo. Criei a nova categoria e mesmo assim não funcionou.

Comment: Alguém para me ajudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verifica o codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Queries#Category_Exclusion

você pode usar nos argumentos do loop:

> 'category__not_in' => '-764'

Ou ainda criar uma ação no seu functions.php

```html
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'wpc_764' );

function wpc_764( $wp_query ) { // deve ser o nome da sua query, preferencialmente único, pois vai alterar em todas as $wp_query
   
    $excluded = array(764);  // coloca num array, caso vc precise excluir mais de uma.
   
    set_query_var('category__not_in', $excluded); // Adiciona category__not_in na query
   
}
```